# Distribution is Weibull but variable diagnostics lines cross and converge - what to do?

Tags: survival, hazard, weibull-distribution

Reproducible data:

```
a<- c(2558,1337,1028,1073,146,9,158,914,394,5163,928,2895,1047,494,685,803,1159,34,3394,2237, 39,729,410,102,5062,479,1944,719,599,1292,2946,788,2571,1688,321,3010,753,613,1675,135,114,1808,2052,24,179,114,1148,3651,85,88,1427,690,5331,522,1054,909,15,3084,1950,2699,1590,1068,2255,792,747,2930,186,4781,424,1462,393,165,46,837,2468,613,1217,718,104,1343,4582,3031,2006,560,655,11,66,360,1138,14,2137,1070,773,900,1648,1643,333,557,514,221)

b<- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1)

require(goft)
require(SurvRegCensCov)
require(survival)

 
goft::weibull_test(a)

SurvRegCensCov::WeibullDiag(Surv(a) ~ b)
```

Backstory: I spent ages trying to force a Cox Proportional Hazard model onto my data (the real one), but none of the hazards are proportional, even when I start adding interactions, so all models failed miserably. I checked for Weibull and the time (duration) data comes back as reasonable (p = 0.57). But **all** my variables, when tested, converge and cross, like above. I have done survival curves using Kaplan - Meier, but I would need to determine significant variables and quantify hazard, and I am at a loss as to how to do that now. Could someone help, please?

---

Edit: the data is a sample of the real data: b is gender and a is duration for a variable (think of e.g. employees at the same location in days). The real data has 2702 observations - but behaves exactly like this sample in terms of survival curves crossing and converging. :-|

Comment: A Weibull model is also a proportional hazards (PH) model, so if PH is violated with a Cox model it also should be violated with a Weibull. If survival curves cross like in your example data then accelerated failure time (AFT) models with their covariate-associated contraction/dilation of the time scale won't work, either. You might need to entertain time-varying coefficients for associations with outcome. Showing real data and results (with variable names changed as needed for confidentiality) might provide better clues for how to proceed.

Comment: @EdM, thank you for the reply. I am **very** new to survival analysis. The data I provided is actually from the real data (b is gender and a is duration in days - think of e.g. employees at the same location), only this is a sample of 100 and the real data has 2702 observations - does this make a difference?

Comment: If the curves in the full data set cross as in this example, then you still have a problem with simple models. You don't, however, seem to be taking "censoring" into account: e.g, individuals who are still in the same location and haven't yet moved. If the "event" is switching location, then you need to include an "event" indicator in your data and to model something like `Surv(time, event) ~ b`. Otherwise, the software assumes that all individuals had an event at the indicated time. Perhaps ignoring that censoring is part of your problem.

Comment: @EdM, no censoring, in the dataset I have all individuals did have an event. What do you mean by saying I still have a problem with simple models? I could not think of any other applicable model given the dataset. If there is anything simpler, I will happily take it!

Comment: So what about all of the _other_ individuals who work at the company but haven't had the event? If you omit them from the study you risk severe bias. That's a fundamental thing to keep in mind about survival models: _all_ those at risk for an event need to be included in the model, whether they have yet experienced the event or not.

Comment: @EdM, the documentation for the Surv() function says that if event is omitted, it is assumed that all observations had an event. Because of this I thought this was a valid approach...? Thanks for the pointer though, appreciate it!

Comment: @EdM, a fantastic thing happened: I have included the no-event data as you advised, and suddenly things seem to work! :-) Thanks! If you want, pls turn your comments into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't need the credit. Why don't you write up a brief answer illustrating how critical it is to include the "censored" cases in survival analysis? You can answer your own question on this site, and even accept it as your favored answer.